# Programmatically Adding Button To Collection View Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have an application in Xcode 4.6. In one view controller I have a collection view. Cells are added to the view via user interaction with the view.  This works fine. I then wanted to add a button (programmatically) to each cell which allows the cell to be deleted. I wanted the button to be located at the top right corner of each cell. The problem is that the button appears in the desired spot within each cell for all cells in the first row of the collection view, (again, top right), but then appears outside of cells for all cells after the first row. See image below:[image]

My button creation method is:

```
-(CollectionViewCellButton *)makeDeleteButtonForCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell
{
  CollectionViewCellButton *button = [CollectionViewCellButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
  CGSize newImageSize = CGSizeMake(cell.frame.size.width/2.5, cell.frame.size.height/2.5);
  UIImage *image = [SeeYourAlbumViewController imageWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"delete"] scaledToSize:newImageSize];

  CGFloat width = image.size.width;
  CGFloat height = image.size.height;
  CGFloat X = cell.frame.size.width - width;
  CGFloat Y = cell.frame.origin.y;

  button.frame = CGRectMake(X, Y, width, height);
  [button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [button addTarget:self
           action:@selector(deleteCollectionViewCell:)
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

  return button;
```

}

The above method is called in my cell creation method as follows:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
             cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView
                              dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"newCell"
                              forIndexPath:indexPath];

  //CALLED HERE!!
  CollectionViewCellButton *cellButton = [self makeDeleteButtonForCell:cell]; 

  cellButton.indexPath = indexPath;
  [cell addSubview:[self.pictures objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; 
  [cell addSubview:cellButton];

  return cell;
}
```

Can anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button is added as a subview of the cell.  It should be using the coordinate system of the cell (bounds) and not the coordinate system of the cell's superview (frame).  In your case, since the button is to be at the top of the cell set

```
CGFloat Y = 0;
```